# Unity UI animation lag

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I play the animation on UI such as loading bar spinning. If the CPU usage is huge such as loading assetBundle or scene, the loading bar will jerk, is there any way to make it play smoothly all the time?

Comment: Post your AssetBundle and scene loading code. I suspect these two are not done properly and are causing this isse.

Comment: @Programmer the problem actually is not assetbundle, it is just an example of heavy calculation, specifically, we have 2 sets of 4000 points. We find the closet point of every point. Is there any way to keep animation loading under such heavy calculation? Or should I calculate some each frame using yield return null instead compute at once?

Comment: Well you didn't mention that. You just blamed the animation. You can use thread to do the calculation since it's just points(`Vector3`). If it's a calculation that requires using Unity API other than `Vector3` or Quaternion then use coroutine and wait for a frame after some few calculations. Using coroutine will be slower but will fix the freezing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned having 2 sets of 4000 points being calculated - are these always going to be the same sets of points every time?

If so, then a trick that's worked for me in the past has been to construct a tool to serialize and write out the calculated results to a file.  Then at runtime you simply read that back in (I moved the data files to StreamingAssets in my case, to make them easier to grab) and deserialize it back into memory, rather than redoing the calculations every startup.

For my project, it helped avoid a setup cost of some 20,000 vertex proximity calcs that otherwise would have spiked horribly.

Also, I'm sure you're already loading your assets using async, but it might be worth double checking the priority of your various AssetBundleRequest calls, and also make sure QualitySettings.asyncUploadTimeSlice isn't too generous.

Comment: Unfortunately one of the set always varies, I will try use coroutine.